# multi values are getting stored in solr document by default in 5.x

Tags: solr

I am quite new to Solr and I have a schema.xml file where i have defined all the fields. But the problem here is the fields are storing as multiple values. I have tried the same in Solr 4.x and everything is working as expected. Am I missing something here?

```
<schema name="aem-solr" version="1.5">
<field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="contentType" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="lastModified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="publishDate" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="sling_resource_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="tags" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Though i am using schema version 1.5 everything is storing as a multivalues as shown below

```
 {
    "id": "/content/geometrixx/en/company/bod",
    "title": [
      "Board of Directors"
    ],
    "url": [
      "/content/geometrixx/en/company/bod.html"
    ],
    "lastModified": [
      "2010-11-312T06:17:30Z"
    ],
    "contentType": [
      "page"
    ],
    "tags": [
      "Investor",
      "Business"
    ],
    "_version_": 1536322934890561500
  }
```

I tried to add multiValued= false attribute to fields but still no luck. I am using SolrJ api for connection and creating documents in Solr server.

Comment: Are you sure it's using the same schema? 5.x switched to the managed schema by default, so it might not be using the schema you think it's using..

Comment: you are correct, when i tried deleting schema.xml file and i restarted solr but still it's working. How to change this default behavior and force to read the schema.xml file for a core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be caused by 5.x using Managed Schema by default - if the correct `schema.xml` file wasn't present when you started Solr for the first time, the created schema will be close to (if not) a Schemaless mode.

> When a  is not explicitly declared in a solrconfig.xml file, Solr implicitly uses a ManagedIndexSchemaFactory, which is by default "mutable" and keeps schema information in a managed-schema file.

You can [revert to the old behavior by changing the Schema Factory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Factory+Definition+in+SolrConfig) back to (or add a definition for) `ClassicIndexSchemaFactory` in `solrconfig.xml`. The link also contains instruction on how you can make Solr import the old schema if you want to use the new Managed Schema factory instead:

> If you have an existing Solr collection that uses
>   ClassicIndexSchemaFactory, and you wish to convert to use a managed
>   schema, you can simplify modify the solrconfig.xml to specify the use
>   of the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory. Once Solr is restarted and it
>   detects that a schema.xml file exists, but the
>   managedSchemaResourceName file (ie: "managed-schema") does not exist,
>   the existing schema.xml file will be renamed to schema.xml.bak and the
>   contents are re-written to the managed schema file.