# Why do all the fields get set to multivalued if I am just setting one field as multivalued in Solr?

Tags: solr

In `schema.xml` I just declared one field to have multiple values using `multiValued="true"` but when I see the response of `*:*` query, I get the values for all the fields inside `[]` (**saying that the particular field is multi-valued**) brackets except the `id` field. Why is it happening can anyone please tell me? U can see the type of response I am getting below:

```
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "name": ["name1"],
      "gender": ["male"],
      "number":["9898989898"]
    }
```

And this is how I declared the field as multi-valued in `schema.xml`:

```
<field name = "id" type = "string" indexed = "true" stored = "true" required="true"/>
<field name = "name" type = "string" indexed = "true" stored = "true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name = "gender" type = "string" indexed = "true" stored = "true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name = "number" type = "string" indexed = "true" stored = "true" required="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure your schame.xml is being used (the default uses the managed-schema now)? Have you deleted all documents and reindexed after changing the schema?

Comment: Following Mats comment, start solr, go into the admin tool (localhost:8983) and use the schema browser to look at your fields. Select core -> schema browser -> field

Comment: I did exactly the same. I changed schema.xml, deleted the current index, stopped solr and started it again. And the name is schema.xml.. I verified @MatsLindh. I have no idea why it is giving unexpected output.

Comment: But are you sure that it's actually using schema.xml? The current version of Solr uses the managed schema by default, and that is kept in Zookeeper and not read from the directory except when starting for the first time. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645464/multi-values-are-getting-stored-in-solr-document-by-default-in-5-x/37653805#37653805

Comment: Really a big thanks to you @MatsLindh. I actually forgot to add `<schemaFactory class = "ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>` in `solrconfig.xml` file. Thanks a lot :). But I want to know one more thing.. Is the field `_version_` really required in the schema.xml? Cz' if I don't use it, solr admin throws an error that `_version_` field must exist and it should be stored and not multivalued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645464/multi-values-are-getting-stored-in-solr-document-by-default-in-5-x/37653805). As `id` is a uniqueKey for the document, it's one of the few fields that's not defined as multivalued in the default, "schemaless" managed schema.

Since 5.x uses Managed Schema by default - if the correct schema.xml file wasn't present when you started Solr for the first time after upgrading, this might happen. You can change this behavior by using the [ClassicIndexSchemaFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Factory+Definition+in+SolrConfig) in your `solrconfig.xml`.

The `_version_` field is required because of Solr internals - it has to be present in the schema, as it's used for partial updates (i.e. someone else has updated the document before you submitted your parts), SolrCloud mode (oh, I already have that version from a different node in the cluster) and the UpdateLog (no need to update what's already present) .. and probably a few other features as well.

Another "magic" field is `_root_`, which is used to implement child document support.